# Feature Construction for Text Classification using Autoencoders

Tags: nlp, text-classification, autoencoder

Autoencoders can be used to reduce dimensionallity in feature vectors - as far as I understand. In text classification a feature vector is normally constructed via a dictionary - which tends to be extremely large. I have no experience in using autoencoders, so my questions are:

1. Could autoencoders be used to reduce dimensionallity in text classification? (Why? / Why not?)
2. Has anyone already done this? A source would be nice, if so.

Answer (score 3):

The existing works use auto encoder for creating models in the sentence level. Basically after training the model using Autoencode, you can get a vector for a sentence. Since any document consists of sentences you can get a set of vectors for the document, and do the document classification. In my experience with various vector representation (e.g. those generated from autoencodes) doing so might give answers worse than classification with bag of words.

Comment: You still represent a sentence as a fixed sized dictionary?

Comment: That is the usual way, since you need a fixed sized vector to do classification with.

Comment: What works best for text in that case from feature engineering perspective? When you want representations at sentence level and for representations for short texts?